# select2 multiple search keyword

Tags: jquery-select2

with select2 plugins is it possible to use multiple search keyword for 1 value

Example:

```
<select>
  <option data-en="Englisch" data-ar="الإنجليزية" data-cn="英语" data-de="Englisch"  value="AL">English</option>
  <option data-en="arabic" data-ar="عربى" data-cn="阿拉伯" data-de="Arabisch"  value="AL">arabic</option>
  <option data-en="Chinese" data-ar="صينى" data-cn="中文" data-de="Chinesisch"  value="AL">Chinese</option>
</select>
```

In search filed if you search in any language (from value or data-attribute) it will show the result

Expected Result:

[Check This Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTN3K.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to override the matcher function completely, as advertised in https://select2.org/searching. Thus you can search for the entered text not only in the text shown for user, but also in the option's metadata.

Here is an incomplete example how to solve this: https://jsfiddle.net/gLhckn7z/.
The comparison function must be improved. It should check all "data" attributes, should compare lower case versions of the data, etc.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('select').select2({
  matcher: function(params, data) {
    if ($.trim(params.term) === '') return data;
    if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') return null;

    // `params.term` should be the term that is used for searching
    // `data.text` is the text that is displayed for the data object
    if (data.text.indexOf(params.term) > -1 
        || $(data.element).data("de").indexOf(params.term) > -1) {
      var modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
      modifiedData.text += ' (matched)';

      return modifiedData;
    }

    // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
    return null;
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: This is incomplete example. Just searches in text and "de" version. Change accordingly to your needs.